# Убрать выделение при нажатии на URL UITextView

Tags: swift, link, uitextview

У меня в UiTextView присутствую ссылки, мне нужно убрать выделение серым цветом при нажатии на них. (подобным образом выделяются по дефолту ячейки у UItableVeiw)
Здесь я могу только задать цвет текста

- linkTextAttributes.

Есть еще эта функция

- func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL,
     in characterRange: NSRange)

Но не могу найти что-то связанное с didSelect или подобное